# Why the connection is getting closed?

Tags: 12.04, vpn, openvpn, error-handling

I have installed Open VPN. Both in my servers and in my computer. I see my log files as :

```
Aug 18 18:37:52 ubuntu openvpn[27920]: Local Options hash (VER=V4): 'bd6dea9e'
Aug 18 18:37:52 ubuntu openvpn[27920]: Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): '760316bb'
Aug 18 18:37:52 ubuntu openvpn[27931]: Attempting to establish TCP connection with x.x.x.x.x.x:80
Aug 18 18:37:52 ubuntu openvpn[27931]: TCP connection established with x.x.x.x:80
Aug 18 18:37:52 ubuntu openvpn[27931]: Socket Buffers: R=[87380->131072] S=[23860->131072]
Aug 18 18:37:52 ubuntu openvpn[27931]: TCPv4_CLIENT link local: [undef]
Aug 18 18:37:52 ubuntu openvpn[27931]: TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: x.x.x.x.x:80
Aug 18 18:37:52 ubuntu openvpn[27931]: WARNING: Bad encapsulated packet length from peer (15393), which must be > 0 and <= 1546 -- please ensure that --tun-mtu or --link-mtu is equal on both peers -- this condition could also indicate a possible active attack on the TCP link -- [Attemping restart...]
Aug 18 18:37:52 ubuntu openvpn[27931]: Connection reset, restarting [0]
Aug 18 18:37:52 ubuntu openvpn[27931]: TCP/UDP: Closing socket
Aug 18 18:37:52 ubuntu openvpn[27931]: /sbin/route del -net x.x.x.x.x. netmask 255.255.255.255
Aug 18 18:37:52 ubuntu openvpn[27931]: /sbin/route del -net 0.0.0.0 netmask 128.0.0.0
Aug 18 18:37:52 ubuntu openvpn[27931]: /sbin/route del -net 128.0.0.0 netmask 128.0.0.0
Aug 18 18:37:52 ubuntu openvpn[27931]: Closing TUN/TAP interface
Aug 18 18:37:52 ubuntu openvpn[27931]: SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
Aug 18 18:37:52 ubuntu openvpn[27931]: Restart pause, 5 second(s)
Aug 18 18:37:57 ubuntu openvpn[27931]: Cannot open file key file 'ovpn.key': No such file or directory (errno=2)
Aug 18 18:37:57 ubuntu openvpn[27931]: Exiting
```

I wonder where is the problem, which makes VPN to reconnect. Note that the file `ovpn.key` is in the current directory!. But still its showing `cannot open file` error message.

Can anybody say me where I'm making mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Always reference you key with an absolute file name, not a relative one!
- If it still doesn't work, check the file permissions.